# How do you target specific set of elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'll just give a quick example to illustrate what I mean with the question.  Say your HTML looks like this...

```
     <div class="tabPanels">
          <ul class="tabs clearfix">
              <li><a href="#panel1">Tab1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#panel2">Tab2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#panel3">Tab3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

How do I target the all the a tags in JavaScript?  I understand that in jQuery you would do the following

```
    $('.tabs li a').click(function(){
       //jquery code here
    });
```

How would I do the exact same thing with pure JavaScript?

Of course I could just do...
       document.getElementsByTagName('a');

However suppose I have multiple li a tags in my webpage, I don't want to target all of them, only a specific set such as the ones above.  Sorry if this is a dumb question.  JQuery makes things easy, but I would like to do better with pure javaScript.

Comment: [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 3):

You have `document.querySelectorAll` function to do that: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Note that is IE8+ function, but in this browser you only use it with CSS2 selectors.

Regards.